# Maximo automation script get user securityGroup

Tags: maximo

I would like to get the security group of the user in a Maximo automation script so I can compare it. I need to know if the user in in MaxAdmin or UserUser group to execute the reste of my script. My scripts are in Python

how could I get that Info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some implicit variables available to you in an automation script (check the IBM Automation Script guide), one of which is the current user's username. There is also the :&USERNAME& special bind variable that gets replaced with the current username. You can use one of those as part of the query to fetch a GroupUser MBO and then check the count of it afterward.

I'm going off of memory here so the exact names and syntax probably differ, but something like:

```
groupUserSet = MXServer.getMXServer().getMboSet("GROUPUSER", MXServer.getMXServer().getSystemUserInfo())
groupUserSet.setWhere("userid = :&USERNAME& and groupname in ('MAXADMIN', 'USERUSER')")
# Not really needed.
groupUserSet.reset()

if groupUserSet.count() > 0:
    # The current user is in one of the relevant groups.
else:
    # The current user is not in one of the relevant groups.
groupUserSet.close()
```

It's worth noting that the kinds of things tied to logic like this usually don't need an automation script. Usually conditional expressions, normal security permissions or reports can do what you need here instead. Even when an automation script like this *is* needed, you still should not do it based on group alone, but based on whether the user has a certain permission or not.

#### EDIT

To do this with permissions, you would add a new sigoption to the app with an id along the lines of "CANCOMPPERM" (with a more verbose description) and grant it to those two groups. Make sure everyone in those groups logs out at the same time (so nobody in those two groups are logged into the system at a given point) or else the permission cache will not update. Your code would then look something like this:

```
permissionsSet = MXServer.getMXServer().getMboSet("APPLICATIONAUTH", MXServer.getMXServer().getSystemUserInfo())
permissionsSet.setWhere("optionname = 'CANCOMPPERM' and groupname in (select groupname from groupuser where userid = :&USERNAME& )")
# Not really needed.
permissionsSet.reset()

if permissionsSet.count() > 0:
    # The current user has the necessary permission.
else:
    # The current user does not have the necessary permission.
permissionsSet.close()
```

I think there are even some helper methods in Maximo's code base that you can call to do the above for you and just return a true/false on if the permission is granted or not.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to get any data, I get this error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count' in <script> at line number 10` I have change `"GROUPUSER"` to `"$GROUPUSER"` but I still get that error.

Comment: Not doing it based on group name but based on a permission being granted is very good advice. The chances of a group being deleted and having another take its place are high, but sig option (permission) names tend to stick around, unchanged.

Comment: @Dex mixed up getMboSet() on Mbo with getMboSet() on MXServer. getMboSet() on MXServer takes an object name as a string and a UserInfo object. You then have to call the setWhere() method on the returned MboSet before you trigger a fetch.

Comment: I may have given too little info. In short, I need that only MaxAdmin and UserUser be able to complete a task that is of the type PERM (all other type are not affected) is it possible to do that with permission?

Comment: I did mix that up. I was in a hurry to do that before heading to work. I'm not sure about the close thing though. I remember looking that up ages ago and learning it was redundant, but I don't remember any more details than that to justify it now.

Comment: You absolutely can do that with permissions. I dislike the implied permissions that using the presence of a specific group gives. You should be using explicit permissions to avoid making things difficult for those that come after you (which might include yourself months or years later, trying to remember how this worked). You would create a new SIGOPTION for the app(s) in question, grant it to those two groups, then do the same logic as above but on the appauth table instead.

Comment: Just to be sure, In your edit, the code is an automation script or it is something else? I am still rather new to Maximo

Comment: It is most of an automation script. The syntax is Python (or Jython). It will not run as-is because it does not contain the imports or the "if" check around it to determine if it is a task of "PERM"-type being completed.

Comment: It seems it will work, I juste need to find my if body. Thanks a lot ^^